# how to start a journal with volumes and issues

Tags: publications, journals

I would like to start a journal and want to know the exact meaning of "volume" and "issue" in publication. What are the rules and recipes if there are any. Thank you

Comment: Don't start a new journal.

Comment: Related: http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/61866/20058

Comment: Before you start a new journal, you should understand the system by working in it for some time; searching papers, reading journals, going to libraries. Why would one start a new journal before one has a picture of how journals work in the first place? The only reason I can imagine for requesting "rules and recipes" for this is, unfortunately, disquieting. Namely, that the publication under consideration here should just appear plausibly to be a journal in form, without even considering relevant content.

Answer (score 1):

There are no rules. These terms date from when the printed versions of journals were paramount. Individual issues of the journal, which might come out monthly or quarterly would be bound together into hardback volumes once or twice a year for long term storage at libraries. The publisher might do this, or they might print the volume number on each issue so that the library would know which issues to combine into an each volume with the library doing or having done the binding itself.

If you want to have issues and volumes in your journal, you may make up whatever system for designating them that you want depending on the frequency you issues come out.